# How to implement custom UIView which is scrollable/zoomable?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, ios8

I want to create  a "timeline" view. I'm comfortable with the `GraphicsContext` drawing API and using it in the `drawRect:` method. What I'm unclear of is the right/idiomatic way to make this view be scrollable/zoomable.

Is it more common to a) subclass `UIScrollView` or b) embed my custom view in stock `UIScrollView` placed inside storyboard?

Depending on which I use, how do I communicate my "desired bounds" to the scrolling machinery? And how do I make my drawing code aware of what the current scale/scroll is so I can draw appropriately.

(I did google for this, and haven't found any recent and simple recipes for this)

Answer (score 1):

Don't subclass or embed.  Set a UIScrollView as the outlet of your viewcontroller.  UIScrollView inherits from UIView so you can treat it just like the normal UIView outlet of your view controller, plus you can scroll it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really understanding what you're suggesting.

Comment: Every UIViewController or subclass there of has an ivar of view so you can access it by typing self.view  
Set self.view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
If you want to do this in interface builder, drag a UIScrollView to onto the screen and delete the UIView that is created for you and drag from the view outlet of your viewcontroller to the new UIScrollView you added.

Comment: Basically, you can replace any UIView with a UIScrollView the same way you can replace any UIView with a UITableView.  In fact UITableView inherits from UIScrollView so UITableView will respond to any selector that UIScrollView would respond to, and UIScrollView will respond to any selector that UIView responds to.

Comment: I think I didn't word this question well Nick, sorry. I'm going to close it. I upvoted your responses as much as I could. :)